# Vault & GKE: Translation failed: invalid ingress spec: failed to validate prefix path /* due to invalid wildcard

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, hashicorp-vault, cert-manager

I'm struggling to deploy Hashicorp's Vault to GKE in HA mode at the moment.

I'm currently running into the following error:

1. `Translation failed: invalid ingress spec: failed to validate prefix path /* due to invalid wildcard Translate`

Within the *vault.yaml* file, I have the ingress set up as follows:

```
ingress:
    enabled: true
    labels:
      traffic: external
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "vault-ui"
      kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
      kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"

    ingressClassName: ""

    pathType: Prefix

    activeService: true
    hosts:
      - host: vault-lab.company.com
        paths:
        - /*
```

According to the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services), "/*" should be fine to use.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try with ImplementationSpecific instead of prefix for the pathType ?

Comment: @boredabdel Thanks! That seems to have done the trick :) I'll have to read up on why that failed. 
If you add that in as the answer I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Posted the comment as an answer. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix is to switch the pathType to ImplementationSpecific instead of Prefix.  /* is only supported with ImplementationSpecific.